# retrieving deep link on destination in Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-deep-link

is there any way to get **deep-link** that has been used to navigate to a **destination**?
in **addOnDestinationChangedListener** method on **navController** there exists a **NavDestination** object, but I was not abled to get the deep-link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is something we can do. this line of code can give us the deeplink:

```
arguments[KEY_DEEP_LINK_INTENT]
```